# Find max apples you can pick ensuring you reach bottom right cell by time T

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, shortest-path

> You start at top-left cell of a given grid. Some cells have wall, some
> you can walk, and some cells have apple. You are given a time limit =
> T, and you should reach bottom right cell by atmost T time. Find
> maximum number of apples you can collect. You cannot visit a cell
> twice. N, M, T <= 14.

I tried a lot of ideas, most promising one is this - rephrase problem as find shortest time to reach destination collecting atleast X apples. Then we could binary search on number of apples.
But I am not able to pin down a solution from last 6hours.
"You cannot visit a cell twice." this is causing me problem.

Any other idea or hint is appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a naive/inefficient solution yet? That's often a good place to start.

Comment: How do time and distance relate? Does walking one cell further take 1 time unit? Does picking apples take time?

Comment: @NicoSchertler Yes, moving between cells take unit of time. 0 unit time to pick up apples

Comment: @Richard Brute solution is straightforward DFS to print all possible paths. It didn't yield any better solution.
My guess is, this could probably boil down to DP(most likely) or to some shortest path problem variant.

Comment: I'd start by doing a BFS from the bottom right. This yields the minimum time needed to reach the finish from every other point on the grid. When deciding whether to move to a cell, add the **time already used** to the **minimum time to reach the end**. If the sum is greater than the time allowed, then moving to that cell is not an option. If there's little extra time, this can significantly reduce the number of paths considered. On the other hand, if there's lots of extra time, then this problem seems harder than the Hamiltonian path problem.

Comment: Yes, @user3386109 . I thought of the same solution. but It still has bad complexity ;/ 
Wait are you saying given problem is NP hard!?

Comment: @MaggiIggam I'll only say this: if the allowed time is greater than the grid size, then finding a  polynomial time solution to this problem proves that P = NP (because determining whether a Hamiltonian path exists between the start and end cells is easily reduced to this problem).

Comment: @user3386109 makes sense. But surely, allowed time can be at max be N x M. since we cannot visit any cell twice, hence problem should be solvable. N, M is very small 14 atmax.

Comment: Regarding the constraints added in rev 3 of the question: if T <= 14, and assuming that diagonal moves are **not** allowed, then the problem size is 3^14 = 4,782,969. That is indeed small enough to solve by brute force.

Comment: If N is 14 and M is 14, T would have to be greater than 14 to reach the end.

Comment: Something seems wrong about the constraints.

Comment: @MaggiIggam is it confirmed that you can move in the four directions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking)? Something like this?

```js
// Heuristic: Manhattan distance to end
function dist(y, x, n, m){
  return n - y + m - x - 2;
}

function getNext(i, j, n, m){
  const ways = [];
  if (i + 1 < n)
    ways.push([i+1, j]);
  if (i > 0)
    ways.push([i-1, j]);
  if (j + 1 < m)
    ways.push([i, j+1]);
  if (j > 0)
    ways.push([i, j-1]);
  return ways;
}

function f(M, T){
  const WALL = 2;
  const n = M.length;
  const m = M[0].length;
  const visited = new Array(n);
  for (let i=0; i<n; i++)
    visited[i] = new Array(m).fill(0);
  let best = 0;
  
  function backtrack(i, j, t, k){
    if (i == n-1 && j == m-1){
      best = Math.max(best, k + M[i][j]);
      return;
    }
 
    for (const [ii, jj] of getNext(i, j, n, m)){
      if (!visited[ii][jj] &&
        M[ii][jj] != WALL &&
        t + dist(ii, jj, n, m) <= T){
        visited[ii][jj] = 1;
        backtrack(ii, jj, t + 1, k + M[i][j]);
        visited[ii][jj] = 0
      }
    }
  }
  
  backtrack(0, 0, 0, 0);
  return best;
}

var N = 8;
var M = 8;
var T = 14;

var matrix = new Array(N);
for (let i=0; i<N; i++)
  matrix[i] = new Array(M).fill(0);
// Apples
matrix[5][5] = 1;
matrix[5][6] = 1;
// Walls
matrix[5][7] = 2;
matrix[5][4] = 2;
matrix[4][4] = 2;
matrix[4][5] = 2;
  
console.log(f(matrix, T));

matrix[5][4] = 0;

console.log(f(matrix, T));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraints, you can use a simple recursive function to complete the problem.

Let `solve(i,j,steps,vis)` be the function, where `(i,j)` are current coordinates, `time` is the time remaining, and `vis` is the set of currently visited nodes. The answer will be `solve(0,0,T,[])`.
The simple recursion would be (using pseudo-code):

```
def solve(i,j,t,vis):
    if (i<0 or i>=n or j<0 or j>=m) return -1
    if ((i,j) in vis) return -1
    if (cell[i][j] == WALL) return -1
    if (t==0){
        if (i==n-1 and j==m-1) return cell[i][j]
        else return -1
    }
    if (i==n-1 and j==m-1) return cell[i][j]

    max_here = cell[i][j]
    temp = max(solve(i,j+1,t-1,vis+(i,j)), solve(i,j-1,t-1,vis+(i,j)), solve(i+1,j,t- 
               1,vis+(i,j)), solve(i-1,j,t-1,vis+(i,j)))  #assuming movement in 4 directions
    if (temp==-1) return -1   # since none of the neighbours lead to destination
    return max_here+temp
```